# slide out navigation loading automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have slide out navigation on my page which is loaded automatically i.e. on the page load.I want that it should only open when user clicks on  the menu bar(in my case it's hamburger sign).

Html code:

```
<i class="fa fa-bars toggle_menu"></i>
<div class="sidebar_menu">
<i class="fa fa-times"></i>
```

js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fa-times").click(function() {
        $(".sidebar_menu").addClass("hide_menu");
        $(".toggle_menu").addClass("opacity_one");
    });
    $(".toggle_menu").click(function() {
        $(".sidebar_menu").removeClass("hide_menu");
        $(".toggle_menu").removeClass("opacity_one");
    });
});
```

Comment: can you post a complete fiddle or snippet?

Comment: There are lots of different ways to do this. Like Hitesh commented, can you provide a working example so we can help with your specific situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to add class `hide_menu` in your HTML itself so that the `sidebar_menu` will be hidden at the time of page load. So modify HTML like:

```
<i class="fa fa-bars toggle_menu"></i>
<div class="sidebar_menu hide_menu">
<i class="fa fa-times"></i>
```